# In WIA, How can I add my program in the program list of acquiring images from a digital camera?

Tags: camera, wia

When I connect my digital camera with my computer, a dialog box containing all the registered programs can be used to get images from the camera will appear. Now I want to add my own program in the list, so that when I click the item of my program, I can use my own program to get images from the digital camera.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

WIA has a Device Manager object that provides an interface that allows for programs to register for event notifications.

### Contacting the Device Manager

You use the `IWiaDevMgr` interface to interact with the device manager. You get a pointer to that interface with a call to `CoCreateInstance()`:

```
    IWiaDevMgr *pWiaDevMgr;
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WiaDevMgr,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
        IID_IWiaDevMgr,
        (void*)&pWiaDevMgr);
```

### Registering a program for an event

Then, registering a program to be run when the event fires is as simple as:

```
pWiaDevMgr->RegisterEventCallbackProgram(
    WIA_REGISTER_EVENT_CALLBACK,
    NULL,
    &WIA_EVENT_DEVICE_CONNECTED,
    bstrCommandline,
    bstrName,
    bstrDescription,
    bstrIcon);
```

The command line, name, description, and icon are all `BSTR`s because they are passing through a COM interface. You can either use `SysAllocString()` and its friends to create them, or use the classes supplied by Visual C extensions or ATL to create and manage them.

### Releasing the Device Manager

If you aren't using a COM-aware smart pointer for the interface, then don't forget to release the reference taken by `CoCreateInstance()`:

```
    pWiaDevMgr->Release();
```

If you don't release it, the COM system *will* find a way to punish you, but it might not be immediately obvious...

### Unregistration

Casual testing shows that deleting a registered event works when all four parameters used to register the event are passed exactly. The call is:

```
pWiaDevMgr->RegisterEventCallbackProgram(
    WIA_UNREGISTER_EVENT_CALLBACK,
    NULL,
    &WIA_EVENT_DEVICE_CONNECTED,
    bstrCommandline,
    bstrName,
    bstrDescription,
    bstrIcon);
```

This is a potential annoyance because there seems to be no documented API to list the registered events. This implies that if your installer registers a program, then it should also keep a record of the arguments used so that your uninstaller can unregister the event.

### The event parameters

The command line can contain the strings `%1` and `%2` which will be replaced by the port name and the GUID of the event that fired, respectively, before the command line is parsed.

The icon , name and description are displayed in the list presented to the user when the camera is plugged in. The name should be shorter than the description.

The icon is a combination of a file name and a resource identifier. A good default value is `"sti.dll,0"` which will be a generic image of a camera and scanner. If you supply your own icon, the string almost certainly must include a fully-qualified path to the DLL. Going out on a limb, I'd imagine that deliberately including a comma anywhere in the path other than as the separator before the resource id will cause trouble.

### Behind the scenes

The actual location where WIA/STI stores the list of events is not documented. However, with a little searching in regedit, I located the event catalog on my XP SP3 system. One might imagine that it would be found in a similar location in other systems...

The registry key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrrentControlSet\Control\StillImage\Events` contains a subkey for each event known to the system. Each key has a value named GUID containing the GUID that identifies that event.

Device Connected event handlers are listed in the `Connect` subkey, for example.

Keys for individual WIA/STI devices can be found in the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{6BDD1FC6-810F-11D0-BEC7-08002BE2092F}` key among other places.

Remember that these locations are not documented. Touch them at your own risk, your mileage will vary, ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the WIA (Windows Image Acquisition) interface. IWiaDevMgr provides three methods to do this: RegisterEventCallbackProgram, RegisterEventCallbackCLSID, and RegisterEventCallbackInterface. If you want Windows to start your program when the user clicks you in the Autoplay dialog, you can use either RegisterEventCallbackProgram or RegisterEventCallbackCLSID.